# What is sys.partitions in mariadb?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

In sql server we can use `sys.partitions`. I need to change my database but I can't find out in mariadb. So I want to know table which like `sys table` in sql server. Could you please to help me?

Comment: Did you get your question answered below by me. Please comment, upvote, downvote, accept answer, or something. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`ALTER TABLE` is how you change table structure.

`UPDATE` is how you change data in a table.

You cannot alter any of the above with the tables in the system database `information_schema`; it is readonly.

Does that address your need to "change my database"?

Comment: No. "Change my database", I mean change others table but use some info from `sys` to detect

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Ex: `SELECT name FROM sys.partition_functions`. Thanks for your help! I will try it by myself :)